# The grep command doesn't show all valid results from the file

Tags: command-line, grep

I compare result of output `grep -i "booting" /var/log/messages.1` which shows:

```
Mar 18 01:20:17 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Mar 18 01:20:17 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Mar 18 03:17:04 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Mar 20 01:41:57 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Mar 20 04:56:54 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
```

and "find" in my Notepad editor:

```
Line 2377: Mar 18 01:20:17 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 2745: Mar 18 01:20:17 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 3342: Mar 18 03:17:04 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 4782: Mar 20 01:41:57 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 5276: Mar 20 04:56:54 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 5683: Mar 20 05:20:23 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 6732: Mar 21 00:53:23 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 7406: Mar 21 12:21:54 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 7948: Mar 21 14:08:13 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
Line 8801: Mar 22 02:39:30 raspberrypi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0x0
```

I cannot understand why grep command didn't show all results?

Comment: Add output of this command to your question: `grep 'Mar 21 00:53:23' /var/log/messages.1 | hexdump -C`

Comment: Maybe the later messages were appended after you checked...

Comment: thank you for suggestion, but it is not a case. the log file messages.1  don't used by system for writing logs. There is a file messages for the purpose.